# javascript dispalying a previous form

Tags: javascript, html

i have a page containing a form that user can fill, inside that form there is some hidden inputs so it depends on which category the user has chosen from the same form the page displays some of hidden inputs that correspond to the category that has been chosen , all forming part of the same form.
now my problem is that when user hit submit button and by the way the action of the form is SELF PHP stay at the same page , once the submit button is clicked
the page displays the default form , and i want it to display the previous form where
the user has been working on.

Comment: <script>
$('#catego').on('change', function(){       
    if ($(this).val() == 1 ) {
        $('#a').removeClass('hide');
        $('#b').addClass('hide');
 $('#c').addClass('hide');
    }
 if ($(this).val() == 2 ) {
        $('#b').removeClass('hide');
        $('#a').addClass('hide');
         $('#c').addClass('hide');
    }

    if ($(this).val() == 3  ) {
        $('#c').removeClass('hide'); 
        $('#a').addClass('hide'); 
 $('#b').addClass('hide'); 
    }
 </script>

Comment: With all due respect, that question is a nightmare to try to read. Please consider rewording it in such a way that the entire paragraph is not just a single sentence. Also the code you have posted as a comment should be entered as a snippet within the question

Comment: No idea what is being asked here. Instead of a big vague explanation, consider adding a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) instead. Please also do not add code as a comment. [Edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/31595766/edit) it instead and [format your code](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I get the point what you wanted to ask.
You can post the chosen category and use it on the page running the same function when the document is ready.
Look:

```
<form method="POST">
    <select id="catego" name="catego">
      <option value="1" <?php if (isset($_POST['catego']) and $_POST['catego'] == '1') echo 'selected'?>>a</option>
      <option value="2" <?php if (isset($_POST['catego']) and $_POST['catego'] == '2') echo 'selected'?>>b</option>
      <option value="3" <?php if (isset($_POST['catego']) and $_POST['catego'] == '3') echo 'selected'?>>c</option>
    </select><br/>
    <input id="a" name="a" type="text" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['a'])) echo $_POST['a']?>"><br/>
    <input id="b" name="b" type="text" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['b'])) echo $_POST['b']?>"><br/>
    <input id="c" name="c" type="text" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['c'])) echo $_POST['c']?>"><br/>
    <input type="submit">
</form>

<script src="lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>

<!-- build:js js/vendor.min.js-->
<!-- bower:js-->
<!-- endbower-->
<!-- endbuild-->
<!-- build:js js/app.min.js-->
<!-- endbuild-->

<script>

function catego() {
    if ($('#catego').val() == 1) {
        $('#a').removeClass('hide');
        $('#b').addClass('hide');
        $('#c').addClass('hide');
    }
    if ($('#catego').val() == 2) {
        $('#b').removeClass('hide');
        $('#a').addClass('hide');
        $('#c').addClass('hide');
    }
    if ($('#catego').val() == 3) {
        $('#c').removeClass('hide');
        $('#a').addClass('hide');
        $('#b').addClass('hide');
    }
}

$('#catego').on('change', catego);

$( document ).ready(function() {
    catego();
});

</script>
```

Good luck!

Comment: Yes It Works Thank yoy